# How Do I Draw a String in an MKOverlayRender

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

The use case I have is one where I want to draw and label counties in a state. Annotations don't seem like the right approach to solve this problem. First of all, the label refers to region rather than a point. Second, there are far too many; so, I would have to selectively show and hide annotations based on zoom level (actually something more like the size of the MKCoordinateRegion span). Lastly, county labels are not all that relevant unless the user starts zooming in.

*Just as a side note, county boundaries may be present in map tiles, but they are not emphasized. Moreover, there are a multitude of other boundaries I might want to draw that are completely absent from map tiles.*

Ultimately, what I want to do is create an overlay for each county shape (counties are clickable and I can navigate to details) and another set of overlays for the labels. I separate county shapes and labels because county shapes are messy and I just use the center of the county. There is no guarantee with this approach that labels will not draw outside of county shapes, which means labels could end up getting clipped when other counties are drawn.

Drawing the county shapes was relatively easy or at least relatively well documented. I do not include any code on rendering shapes. Drawing text on the other hand is not straight forward, not well documented, and most of the posts on the subject are ancient. The lack of recent posts on the subject as well as the fact that most posts posit solutions that no longer work, use deprecated APIs, or only solve a part of the problem motivates this post. Of course, the lack of activity on this problem could be because my strategy is mind numbingly stupid.

I have posted a complete solution to the problem. If you can improve on the solution below or believe there is a better way, I would appreciate the feedback. Alternatively, if you are trying to find a solution to this problem, you will find this post more helpful than the dozens I have looked at, which on the whole got me to where I am now.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a complete solution that can be run in an Xcode single view Playground. I am running Xcode 14.2. The most important bit of code is the overridden draw function of LabelOverlayRenderer. That bit of code is what I struggled to craft for more than a day. I almost gave up. Another key point is when drawing text, one uses CoreText. The APIs pertaining to drawing and managing text are many and most have had a lot of name changes and deprecation.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import SwiftUI

class LabelOverlayRenderer: MKOverlayRenderer {
    let title: String
    let center: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    
    init(overlay: LabelOverlay) {
        center = overlay.coordinate
        title = overlay.title!
        super.init(overlay: overlay)
    }
    
    override func draw(_ mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, in context: CGContext) {
        context.saveGState()
        // Set Drawing mode
        context.setTextDrawingMode(.fillStroke)
        // If I don't do this, the text is upside down.
        context.textMatrix = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, -1.0);
        // Text size is crazy big because label has to be miles across
        // to be visible.
        var attrs = [ NSAttributedString.Key : Any]()
        attrs[NSAttributedString.Key.font] = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 128000.0)!
        attrs[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor] = UIColor(Color.red)
        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: title, attributes: attrs)
        let line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(attributedString)
        // Get the size of the whole string, so the string can
        // be centered. CGSize is huge because I don't want
        // to clip or wrap the string. The range setting
        // is just cut and paste.  Looks like a place holder.
        // Ideally, it is the range of that portion
        // of the string for which I want the size.
        let frameSetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attributedString)
        let size = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(frameSetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), nil, CGSize(width: 1000000, height: 1000000), nil)
        
        // Center is lat-lon, but map is in meters (maybe? definitely
        // not lat-lon). Center string and draw.
        var p = point(for: MKMapPoint(center))
        p.x -= size.width/2
        p.y += size.height/2
        // There is no "at" on CTLineDraw. The string
        // is positioned in the context.
        context.textPosition = p
        CTLineDraw(line, context)
        
        context.restoreGState()
    }
}

class LabelOverlay: NSObject, MKOverlay {
    let title: String?
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let boundingMapRect: MKMapRect
    
    init(title: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, boundingMapRect: MKMapRect) {
        self.title = title
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.boundingMapRect = boundingMapRect
    }
}

class MapViewCoordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        if let overlay = overlay as? LabelOverlay {
             return LabelOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        }
        
        fatalError("Unknown overlay type!")
    }
}


struct MyMapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeCoordinator() -> MapViewCoordinator {
        return MapViewCoordinator()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context){
        // Center on Georgia
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 32.6793, longitude: -83.62245)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 4.875, longitudeDelta: 5.0003)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: span)
        view.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 32.845084, longitude: -84.3742)
        let mapRect = MKMapRect(x: 70948460.0, y: 107063759.0, width: 561477.0, height: 613908.0)
        let overlay = LabelOverlay(title: "Hello World!", coordinate: coordinate, boundingMapRect: mapRect)
        view.addOverlay(overlay)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        // Create a map with constrained zoom gestures only
        let mapView = MKMapView(frame: .zero)
        mapView.isPitchEnabled = false
        mapView.isRotateEnabled = false
        
        let zoomRange = MKMapView.CameraZoomRange(
            minCenterCoordinateDistance: 160000,
            maxCenterCoordinateDistance: 1400000
        )
        mapView.cameraZoomRange = zoomRange
        return mapView
    }
    
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MyMapView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```